# Using Capacitor 3 with Nuxtjs SSR

Tags: nuxt.js, capacitor

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.15.4 ssr mode and I wanna add Capacitorjs 3 to my project. As I read the doc, I found out for `webDir` we should add `dist` directory that is created by `npm run generate` which is for static mode `target: static` not `npm run build` (for ssr apps).

So what is the correct way of configurating Capacitor for SSR Nuxt??

Comment: What did you tried so far? Does this codesandbox help: https://codesandbox.io/s/79cm0 Looks like it's totally configured already. There is this one also: https://github.com/MexsonFernandes/nuxt-ionic-capacitor-app

Comment: Hmmm... , the serverMiddleware ! huh! gonna try that. tanx

Comment: Yes, this is only related to server and some Node.js.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue with my Nuxt SSR - did you figure out what `webDir` needs to be set as? I've tried setting it to `.nuxt` and `dist` (which doesn't exist as it's srr) but no luck

Comment: @JonathanRobbins you don't ever need to touch to `.nuxt` (cache) nor `dist` (final built directory).

Comment: It's not the `.nuxt` or `dist` directory that I am touching, its value of `webDir` in `capacitor.config.json` @MojtabaBarari used to solve the original issue I want to know

Comment: @JonathanRobbins maybe you can get inspired from what Quasar is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Define a server url**

I have a Nuxt app in SSR mode, with CapacitorJS. Ultimately after relevant steps, it successfully runs in my Android Studio emulator and on my physical Pixel 2 (manual apk install). I haven't yet fully tested in production or in iOS XCode.

Defining a server URL was the trick. Initially I was wrestling with `webdir` like everyone else, although this doesn't seem to be needed if using the `server: {url: }` property.

**capacitor.config.json:**

```
{
    "appId": "io.mysillyapp.app",
    "appName": "My Silly App",
    "server": {
        "url": "https://mysillyapp.myapphosting.io"
    },
    "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/snap/bin/android-studio"
}
```

**Optionally wrap in a condition, like so ([link](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3217#discussioncomment-34696)):**

```
{
  ...
  server: process.env.HOST ? { url: `${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT ?? 8100 }` : undefined
  ...
}
```

**After running `npx cap copy`, you'll see a warning:**

```
 Web asset directory specified by webDir does not exist. This is not an error because server.url is set in config.
```

If you care about this warning and think you need it, then define `webDir`; I have it pointing to `.nuxt`:

```
{
    ...
    "webDir": ".nuxt",
    ...
}
```

**NOTES:**

[Capacitor docs for `server url`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/config) says *"This is not intended for use in production"* without additional explanation. What does it mean, I don't know. My first thought is they're being conservative here with the presumption that Apple may not like this in an app submission (From a high-level, Apple wants real apps, not websites-wrapped-as-apps).

However, a commenter seems to be **[successfully using `server url` in production](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/1478#discussioncomment-1344330)**, having passed app store submissions.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/config

```
  /**
     * Load an external URL in the Web View.
     *
     * This is intended for use with live-reload servers.
     *
     * **This is not intended for use in production.**
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    url?: string;
```

Comment: Additionally Dan Pastori seems to have a ton of knowledge on this topic. Here's a relevant reddit dicussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/qo0i19/comment/hjp0fnx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3